# why is the load method only adding one row to my datatable rather than all rows retrieved by the stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, ado.net

When i execute the stored procedure in sql server passing in the right parameter, two rows are returned as expected. I have dragged the same stored procedure object to my dataset xsd file in visual studio, but when i call the load method on this stored procedure object, it only populate with one record/row rather than 2 as expected. Here is my code below. Keep in mind that i have done the same thing with actual tables as well which works fine but not with this stored proc representing a datatable. Can someone please help with why i am not getting 2 rows returning. Thank you

```
    public PortfolioDataSet.GetUserEducationDataTable GetUserEducations(Guid UserID)
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = USER_ID;
            parameter.Value = UserID;

            command = new SqlCommand(GET_USER_EDUCATION, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            myDataSet.GetUserEducation.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != command)
            {
                command.Dispose();
                command = null;
            }
            if (null != connection)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return myDataSet.GetUserEducation;
    }
```

Stored procedure is bellow

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetUserEducation](@UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT 
        usr_ID,
        ed_CourseTitle,
        ed_PeriodFrom,
        ed_PeriodTo,
        ed_PlacementYear,
        sch_Name
    FROM 
        [User]
        INNER JOIN Education ON Education.ed_User = [User].usr_ID
        INNER JOIN School ON School.sch_ID = Education.ed_School
    WHERE
        usr_ID = @UserID
END
```

Comment: Do you have SQL Profiler? You may need to check what sql is running against the DB. You can also use the debugger from Visual Studio to step through your code

Comment: I'd have to see the body of your stored procedure.  Is it returning two rows in one result-set, or one row in each of two result-sets?

Comment: @pmbAustin i have added the proc, please let me know if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: Can you post the implementation of the myDataSet.GetUserEducation.Load() method?

Comment: @pmbAustin the Load method is a method from the stored procedure DataTable i dragged from my server explorer into my dataset. This is an ADO.NET method, i did not write the Load() method.